# Eager loading an association of a singular association from an instantiated ActiveRecord object in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model `User`, that `has_one :child`, and the `Child` model `has_one :toy`.

If I have a single instance of the User class `user`, how can I load both the child and toy in one query?

Here's what doesn't work:

```
user.child.toy # 2 queries
user.includes(child: :toy) # can't call includes on a single record
user.child.includes(:toy) # same as above
user.association(:child).scope.eager_load(:toy).first # makes the appropriate query with both child and toy... but doesn't set the object on the user model.
user.child = user.association(:child).scope.eager_load(:toy).first # makes the appropriate query, but also calls another query before setting the child :(
```

Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve re-querying the user model. ie. I want to avoid this

```
User.where(id: user.id).eager_load(child: :toy).first
```

---

Relavant model declarations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :child
  has_one :toy, through: :child
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :toy
  belongs_to :user
end

class Toy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :child
end
```

---

### Update

This works, but isn't ideal. I don't think I should have to declare another relation solely for this reason.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :child
  has_one :toy, through: :child
  has_one :child_with_toy, ->{ eager_loads(:toy) }, class_name: "Child", foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

which allows me to call `user.child_with_toy` to get the `Child` object, and `user.child_with_toy.toy` to get the `Toy` object, while only triggering one SQL query.

Comment: I do now really know how to do this, but I was searching online and found a post discussing about it https://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Comment: Please post the relevant sections of your `User` model and `Child` model showing exactly how/where the `:child` and `:grandchild` associations are defined. Thanks.

Comment: @Nathan I updated the question to use different model names to make it more clear how the relations are defined, and added some relevant psuedo code.

Comment: I believe your `:child_with_toy` approach is the cleanest approach you will find for your scenario. If you had multiple users or multiple children, there might be better options.

Comment: I am curious, why would you care? I can understand optimization for collections or large record sets, but for this type of queries what is the concern?

Comment: @s1mpl3 I'm just trying to reduce queries in our application layout. Every single page on our app uses the same layout, and reducing one query there might be worth it - if I could get it to work so I could benchmark it. :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Remember "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to eager load an association of a singular association for an already-instantiated record, you can do this:

```
user.association(:child).target = user.association(:child).scope.eager_load(:toy).first
```

This is similar to one of the approaches you listed at the top of your question. In particular, notice the `.target` part.

`ActiveRecord` isn't optimized for this particular scenario, so the code is pretty ugly. For that reason, I would strongly lean toward your `:child_with_toy` approach if you really need to save the query.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is pretty ugly, but looks like there are no alternatives :(

Answer (score 5):

It can be done easier with `Preloader`:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(user, child: [:toy])
```